# Can't get data from react webview in react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, yandex-maps

Can't get data from postMessage. I want get coordinates from webview yandex map. Please help me get data. Chat gpt useless for me, all his suggestion useless in this task.

```
// mobile app
    const handleMap = (event) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
        console.log('Received data from WebView:', data);
    };

<WebView
  style={styles.container}
  ref={webViewRef}
  source={{ uri: 'http://localhost:3000/map' }}
  onMessage={handleMap}
 />

// web app 

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleMessage = (event) => {
            const data = event.data;
            console.log('Web app:', data);
        };

        window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleData = (value, coordinates, apartmentNumber, officeNumber, phoneNumber) => {
        setData({address: value, coordinates, apartmentNumber, office: officeNumber, other: phoneNumber});
        setTimeout(() => {
            sendData();
        }, 100);
    };

    const sendData = () => {
        console.log('send');
        const info = { message: data };
        console.log('sendData', info);
        window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(info), '*');
        window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(info), '*');
    };
```

i expect get data from webview i need get coordinates.